# Requiring an SQLite database stops pages from rendering

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, express

I'm trying to implement an SQLite3 database in my Node/Express application as per this [tutorial](https://developerhowto.com/2018/12/29/build-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-express-js/). However, whenever I try to include it, my pages stop rendering. Here's the database code:

database.js

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()
var md5 = require('md5')

const DBSOURCE = "db.sqlite"

let db = new sqlite3.Database(DBSOURCE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      // Cannot open database
      console.error(err.message)
      throw err
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to the SQLite database.')
        db.run(`CREATE TABLE user (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name text, 
            email text UNIQUE, 
            password text, 
            CONSTRAINT email_unique UNIQUE (email)
            )`,
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                // Table already created
            }else{
                // Table just created, creating some rows
                var insert = 'INSERT INTO user (name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?)'
                db.run(insert, ["admin","admin@example.com",md5("admin123456")])
                db.run(insert, ["user","user@example.com",md5("user123456")])
            }
        });  
    }
});

module.exports = { db }
```

app.js

```
'use strict';

// requirements
const express = require('express');
const db = require("database.js")
const { render } = require('ejs');

// constants
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// main express program
const app = express();

// configurations
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static('views'))
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');


app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.render(__dirname + "/views/index.ejs");
});

module.exports = { app }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
  }
}
```

If I get rid of `const db = require("database.js")` in app.js it works and the page renders fine. Any ideas why?